# how to print sonar rule as a comment in java code in intelij/Eclipse if not fixed?

Tags: intellij-idea, sonarlint

We are in a process to enforce java coding standards into project. We are using Eclipse and intelij as IDE.

What we are looking for?

If a Sonar rule violates and not get fixed, the it should appear as comment on top of the code. So that, if someone tries to push it without fixing, it will appear in the code at the time of code review.

For example:

```
String a = "Test";
String b = "test";

if(a==b) {

 }
```

It should come as :

```
String a = "Test";
String b = "test";

// @sonar.issue(type="java:S106", severity="warning")
if(a==b) {

 }
```

until it gets fixed.

What I did:

In the properties section, I added the property:

```
Print rule violations as comments: true
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to use SonarQube so the issues are reported during the Code Review and can actually be a merging condition, for example.

Comment: SonarQube need to be configured in local IDE too?

Comment: It's better to use SonarLint in connected mode with SonarQube so each of your developers has access to the same rules within the IDE while coding. But ultimately, if your goal is to show the issues during the code review, this is on SonarQube side.